# Comparing multiple values from database with one textbox value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to compare database values with the text box values.
For suppose,if the database returns one value then i am able to compare and process the next step.
But i am unable to process when multiple values are retrieved from the database.
I am using the below code:

Example:

```
$var = robert;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select name from hm where class = 8");
```

Database values:

### name

steve

Maxy

Rock

```
if($var != $qwery)
{
//do something;
}
else
{
//do this;
}
```

Please help me with the problem.Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What driers are you using to connect to the DB? Where is sample code?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How is a single variable assignment, which isn't even valid PHP code, an example of what you're doing. Show the database query you're trying to do. Why can't you process when multiple values (do you mean multiple rows or multiple columns?) are returned?

Comment: I have edited and added details to my question,sorry about the last question.Please review and solve my problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should either loop through the array that is returned, or use something like `array_search()`, to determine if your desired value is contained within the array.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming you are posting the textbox values in a form. You could then do something like this

First I would make an array from your query results.

```
$arrayToCheck = array();
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select name from hm where class = 8");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arrayToCheck[] = $res['name'];
}
```

then

```
if(in_array($_POST['name_from_form'], $arrayToCheck)){
    //do something;
} else {
    //do this;
}
```